# Being semantic when swapping between various h1 titles using media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, semantics

I'm creating a coming soon page but want the h1 header to have different titles as the screen widths change. Here's my problem though:

```
 <h1 class="hide1">HOLD ONTO YOUR HATS</h1>
 <h1 class="hide2">COMING SOON</h1>
 <h1 class="hide3">ON ITS WAY</h1>
 <h1 class="hide4">PENDING</h1>
 <h1 class="hide5">NIGH</h1>
```

...and then:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
      .hide2, .hide3, .hide4, .hide5 {
         display: none;
      }
 }
```

This is all a bit chopped and hacked together.

Is there a more semantic way of doing this that will 1, hide the other h1's in the source code and 2, Hide the other h1's from screen readers?

Thanks

edit: The title was a little confusing so it has been changed

Comment: Are you use javasript too in your project?

Comment: No, just css if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't seem to be able to question something in a way that's making sense, something to work on in the future I guess.

So after working on it for the past couple of days I think I may have found a solution that is less hacky.

```
 <h1><span class="main__header--changer">COMING SOON</span></H1>
```

...and the css

```
 @media (max-width: 75em) {
      h1:before {
           content: "HOLD ONTO YOUR HATS";
      }

      .main__header--changer {
           display: none;
      }
 }
```

The only thing is though screen readers won't be able to read the header.